# npm: ERR on every command

Tags: node.js, npm

Any command I try to run with npm, gives me an error. All except checking for their version numbers.

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm cache clean 
>   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g n 
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "n"
>   npm ERR! node v6.11.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
>   npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@2.1.12: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>   npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
>   npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
>   npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
>   npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

Comment: deinstall node and install it again :)

Comment: Just use the proper Node.js Windows installer and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not a windows user, Did a quick googling and found this]

https://github.com/tj/n/issues/491

Duplicate: [#435](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/435)

**n doesn't support windows**, or at least not x64 but brodybits on that 
issue mentioned https://github.com/jasongin/nvs

Hope this helps